# Translating idempotent merge example not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get this merge statement to handle (just inserts for now) in an idempotent way? I would like to follow this rough example / template proposed by [databricks](https://github.com/databricks/tech-talks/blob/master/2020-05-28%20%7C%20Slowly%20Changing%20Dimensions%20(SCD)%20Type%202/SCD%20Type%202%20Blog%20Demo.sql).

The example data contains a base set with 2 rows for 2 dates. The change set contains 2 rows for 2 dates, with 1 row being a duplicate, and 1 row being "new" data that should be "merged".

#### Some data

```
create table #baseset
(
 Date varchar(30),
 ID varchar(30),
 State varchar(30),
 Count varchar(30)

)
insert into #baseset values('2/7/2023', 'A', 'A',   null)
insert into #baseset values('2/6/2023', 'A', 'A',   null)

create table #changeset
(
 Date varchar(30),
 ID varchar(30),
 State varchar(30),
 Count varchar(30)

)
insert into #changeset values('2/8/2023',   'A', 'A',   null)
insert into #changeset values('2/7/2023',   'A', 'A',   null)
```

#### Mockup MERGE

```
(
  -- These rows will either UPDATE the existing data or INSERT new data that does not yet exist
  SELECT
    #changeset.ID as mergeKey, #changeset.*
  FROM
    #changeset
  UNION ALL
    -- These rows will INSERT data of existing rows
    -- Setting the mergeKey to NULL forces these rows to NOT MATCH and be INSERTed.
  SELECT
    NULL as mergeKey,
    #changeset.*
  FROM
    #changeset
    JOIN #baseset ON #changeset.ID = #baseset.ID
  WHERE
    #changeset.Date <> #baseset.Date
)
```

#### Yielding

```
+--------+--------+---+-----+-----+
|mergeKey|    Date| ID|State|Count|
+--------+--------+---+-----+-----+
|       A|2/8/2023|  A|    A| null|
|       A|2/7/2023|  A|    A| null|
|    null|2/8/2023|  A|    A| null|
|    null|2/7/2023|  A|    A| null|
|    null|2/8/2023|  A|    A| null|
+--------+--------+---+-----+-----+
```

#### Expected

```
+--------+--------+---+-----+-----+
|mergeKey|    Date| ID|State|Count|
+--------+--------+---+-----+-----+
|       A|2/8/2023|  A|    A| null|
|       A|2/7/2023|  A|    A| null|
|    null|2/8/2023|  A|    A| null|
+--------+--------+---+-----+-----+
```

#### Full Merge Statement

Its the same query as above.

```
MERGE INTO #baseset
USING (
  -- These rows will either UPDATE the existing data or INSERT new data that does not yet exist
  SELECT
    #changeset.ID as mergeKey, #changeset.*
  FROM
    #changeset
  UNION ALL
    -- These rows will INSERT data of existing rows
    -- Setting the mergeKey to NULL forces these rows to NOT MATCH and be INSERTed.
  SELECT
    NULL as mergeKey,
    #changeset.*
  FROM
    #changeset
    JOIN #baseset ON #changeset.ID = #baseset.ID
  WHERE
    #changeset.Date <> #baseset.Date
) staged_updates
ON #baseset.id = mergeKey
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
  INSERT (Date, ID, State, Count)
  VALUES (staged_updates.Date, staged_updates.ID, staged_updates.State, staged_updates.Count)
;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merge" here? `MERGE` is an operator in T-SQL. The "merge statement" you've provided is not a `MERGE`, but looks to be a derived table from part of a larger query.

Comment: Its just a mock up of what would happen with the MERGE. The statement is the same and is included now.

Comment: I would suggest perhaps not using `MERGE`. It has lots of challenges. https://sqlblog.org/merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're kinda mixing up your terminology, but anyways.
The canonical merge example with your data:

```sql
drop table #baseset
drop table #changeset
go

create table #baseset
(
 Date varchar(30),
 ID varchar(30),
 State varchar(30),
 Count varchar(30)

)
insert into #baseset values('2/7/2023', 'A', 'A',   null)
insert into #baseset values('2/6/2023', 'A', 'A',   null)

create table #changeset
(
 Date varchar(30),
 ID varchar(30),
 State varchar(30),
 Count varchar(30)

)
insert into #changeset values('2/8/2023',   'A', 'A',   3)
insert into #changeset values('2/7/2023',   'A', 'A',   4)

;merge #baseset as t
using #changeset as s
 ON s.date = t.date
 and s.ID = t.ID
when matched then update
  set state = s.state
  , count = s.count
 when not matched by target then insert 
  (date, id, state, count)
  values (s.date, s.id, s.state, s.count)
  ;
 select *
 from #baseset
```

This does a so called upsert which updates #baseset from the #changeset when ID and date matches, and when not matched by #baseset (ie. missing), it inserts the missing rows